# How to use for loop in Javascript to print 1...10 numbers without assignment

Tags: javascript

I have one question, how to use for loop in javascript to print the 1...10 numbers
without using assignment operator.

Usually we do  `for(i=1;i<=10;i++) { console.log(i); }`  but how we can use same without assign value in  `i`

Comment: Use while and increment the variable value.

Comment: You might want to ask this on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Updated answer:

```js
[ ...Array(10) ].forEach((e, i) => console.log(++i));
```

*Explanation*:

- `Array(10)` creates an array with 10 empty items (which means the array c̲a̲n̲n̲o̲t̲ be iterated yet).
- `[ ...Array(10) ]` uses a spread operator to extract the 10 empty items to an array (and apparently makes the value of each be `undefined`. Would be great if someone could explain why).
- Since the result of `[ ...Array(10) ]` is an array, array functions could be used (`.forEach()`, `.map()`, etc.). [Check about array functions here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Instance_methods)

---

**Old Answer:**

Another approach (in ES6) but similar to @Nina Scholz's answer...

```js
new Array(10).fill().forEach((e, i) => console.log(++i));
```

The second paramter of the function in `forEach()` is the **index**. This way, there is no need for `Object.keys()`.

*Explanation:*

- `new Array(10)` creates an array with 10 *empty items* (which means the array c̲a̲n̲n̲o̲t̲ be iterated yet).
- `.fill()` fills the array with `undefined` (which means the array c̲a̲n̲ now be iterated).
- `.forEach((e, i) => {})` loops through the array. It takes in a function with two parameters, the first (`e`) being *each element* of the array, the second (`i`) being the index of the current loop.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this prevents YOU from assigning the variable, a lot of values are being assigned. You have all the attributes and methods on the Array prototype, all the memory allocations of type `undefined` in each bucket, an iterator for the spread (which ironically is a for loop under the hood) and another iterator for your forEach (also a for loop under the hood), and finally all of the method signature values for the inline function. This is a very memory inefficient approach. For those that care about performance, use the standard for loop.

Answer (score 3):

for loop

no assignment

```
for(var i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) console.log(i);
```

Done

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array, fill it, take the keys and slice it. After all display the indices.

```js
Object.keys(Array(11).fill()).slice(1).forEach(i => console.log(i));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].forEach(function(i) {
  console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: Or one line with an arrow function

Comment: the question asks *how to use **for loop***  :p

Comment: yep `for(i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]){console.log(i)}`

Answer (score 0):

For a kind of `for` loop and no assignment operator..?

```js
for (var i in Array.from(Array(10))) console.log(+i+1);
```